# How to correctly call enum methods in an hql request ? numberClass and symbolClass is an enums

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, hql

> Error creating bean with name 'studentRepository': Invocation of init
> method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List

```
    @Query(
        "SELECT new com.javamentor.dto.model.student.StudentDto(" +
                "s.id, " +
                "s.firstName, " +
                "s.lastName, " +
                "s.middleName, " +
                "s.birthday, " +
                "s.email, " +
                "s.enabled, " +
                "s.registrationDate, " +
                "s.enrollmentDate, " +
                "CONCAT(s.studentClass.classLevel.numberClass.ordinal, 
                        s.studentClass.symbolClass.name)) " +
                "FROM Student s")
    List<StudentDto> findAllStudentsDTO();
```

Comment: `cast(enumValue as text)` works for me (string enumerated type)

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it. You should pass enums to your `StudentDto` constructor and then concatenate them as you wish.